# Java Regex not picking up multiple occurences over multiple lines

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a text pattern of `[[1st-word | 2nd-word]]` or `[[word]]` using java regex span over multiple lines. For example, my code is

```
String tStr = "Computer science in sport''' is an interdisciplinary discipline 
that has its goal in combining the theoretical as well as practical aspects 
and methods of the areas of [[Information technology|informatics]] and [[sport 
science]]. The main emphasis of the [[interdisciplinarity]] is placed on the 
application and use of computer-based but also mathematical techniques in sport 
science, aiming in this way at the support and advancement of theory and practice 
in sports.&lt;ref&gt;{{cite web|author=Daniel Link &amp; Martin Lames|title=Sport 
Informatics – Historical Roots";

String validateRegex = "(\\[\\[)(:?)(\\w+)(\\|?)(\\w*)(\\]\\])";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(validateRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tStr);
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group()+"\n");
}
```

outputs `[[interdisciplinarity]]`. However, I expected to see

```
[[Information technology|informatics]]
[[sport science]]
[[interdisciplinarity]]
```

Can anybody help clarify where is my mistake? and give me an example how can I extract the expected pattern correctly ?

Comment: A String is not multiline if there is no `\n` in it. Writing it in multiple lines in the source doesn't add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[Information technology|informatics]]

and

[[sport science]]

contains space, that is not present in your regex.